# Not fetching correct canonical URL when tag is multiline, How to grep canonical URL when it's tag is multiline?

Tags: html, regex, ruby, web-scraping

I am trying to collect canonical URLs by scraping web pages. My regex is able to bring the URL when tag is single line. But fetching wrong results when tag is multiline.

#### Attempt

```
(?<=<link(?:\s|\n)href=)"(.+?)"(?= rel="canonical">)
```

Please go through this link for inputs and regex I tried https://rubular.com/r/M5WzfdXXe9y9sI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, it would also work without lookarounds:

```
<link\s+href="([^"]+)"\s+rel="canonical"\s*>
```

or

```
<link\s+href="([^"]*)"\s+rel="canonical"\s*>
```

#### Test

```
re = /<link\s+href="([^"]+)"\s+rel="canonical"\s*>/si
str = '<link href="http://www.naviscent.com"   rel="canonical"> <link href="http://www.naviscent.com/ar" hreflang="ar-SA" rel="alternate"> <link href="http://www.naviscent.com/eu" hreflang="eu-ES" rel="alternate">
<link  href="http://www.naviscent.com"   rel="canonical"> <link href="http://www.naviscent.com/ar" hreflang="ar-SA" rel="alternate"> <link href="http://www.naviscent.com/eu" hreflang="eu-ES" rel="alternate">'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

---

#### Output

```
["http://www.naviscent.com"]
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8g2Y5c/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8g2Y5c/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The href value is in Capture group 3

`<link(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\srel\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*canonical\s*\1))(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*?)\s*\2))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://rubular.com/r/bdNhxYpUZfGXCo

Formatted / explained

```
 < link                 # link  tag

 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s rel \s* = \s*       # rel attribute
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           \s* canonical \s*      # With "canonical" value
           \1 
      )
 )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s href \s* = \s*      # href attribute
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (2), Quote
           \s* 
           (                      # (3 start), href value
                (?:
                     (?! \2 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
           )                      # (3 end)
           \s* 
           \2 
      )
 )
                        # Conditions satisfied, get the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```